# Correct way to pass Entity objects between layers?

Tags: entity-framework-4, idisposable, objectcontext

I am just learning the Entity Framework and have made some good progress on incorporating it with my layered code structure.  I have 2 visual layers, a business layer and a data access layer.

My problem is in passing entity object between layers.  This code sample does not work:

```
// BLL
public static void Test1()
{
 List<User> users = (from u in GetActiveUsers()
      where u.ID == 1
      select u).ToList<User>();

 // Do something with users
}

// DAL
public static IQueryable<User> GetActiveUsers()
{
 using (var context = new CSEntities())
 {
  return from u in context.Users
      where u.Employee.FirstName == "Tom"
      select u;
 }
}
```

I get the error message *The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*

If I remove the *using* from the GetActiveUsers method, it works fine.

I know this is dangerous practice as the GC can dispose of the context at any given time and screw up my BLL.

So, what is the correct way to pass information between layers?  Do I need to pass the context around as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are returning **IQueryable** from your DAL, you cannot use the **using** statement.

The query is *deferred* until to are firing the query - **.ToList** in your BLL.

By that time, the context is disposed.

Think *carefully* about using IQueryable, as it is risky practice without knowing all the details.

Since you are still learning EF, i would keep it simple:

```
// BLL
public static void Test1()
{
 List<User> users = GetActiveUsers();
 var singleUser = users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == 1);

 // Do something with users
}

// DAL
public static ICollection<User> GetActiveUsers()
{
 using (var context = new CSEntities())
 {
  var users = from u in context.Users
      where u.Employee.FirstName == "Tom"
      select u;
  return users.ToList();
 }
}
```

If you want to get a single user, create another method:

```
// DAL
public static User GetSingleActiveUser(int userId)
{
 using (var context = new CSEntities())
 {
  var users = from u in context.Users
      where u.Employee.UserId == userId
      select u;
  return users.SingleOrDefault();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, if I convert my entity to a list in the DAL, don't I lose all the functionality that I get with EF?  Like, if I want to be able to page in Silverlight, I wouldn't necessarily want to load the entire dataset into a list, right?

Comment: Sort of. With IQueryable, you can 'build up' queries later on (ie deferred execution). Which gives you a lot of power. I also use IQueryable's. But as i said, you cannot use the 'using' statement when using IQueryable. You need to manually open/close the context from somewhere else, i strongly recommend a IoC container (like StructureMap) for this. Otherwise you'll end up with old connections hanging around.

Comment: And no - you don't really lose the functionality, you just lose the ability to have coarse grained control over the queries outside the DAL. You can still do paging, just create a method which accepts a page number and page size, then page inside the actual DAL method and return the List. Have a look at some of my questions i've asked if you're interested in IQueryable, because as i said i currently use it. Also, letting the Silverlight app execute the queries is too late. You should only defer the query to the BLL, no later. Otherwise you could have unexpected results.