# Common LINQ method using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

So this is probably a stupid question, but I am still not exactly sure how the entity frameworks objects work. I am using EF4 in an MVC3 app, and have two controllers that need to use the same LINQ query against it. Is it best to use a static method that takes the db entity by ref, or should the method use a "using" block for its own entity (as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101502/correct-way-to-pass-entity-objects-between-layers))?

I would think the using block would add additional overhead, but I didn't find any examples of the other method. Is there a proper way to make "library" methods for EF access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an MVC application the `ObjectContext` should be scoped to the request. Most DI containers can do this automatically. So you would prefer *not* using a `using` block within a method. Instead inject the context via the constructor or pass it as a method argument.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but what does DI stand for in this instance?

Comment: Dependency Injection. Example containers are AutoFac, Structure Map, and NInject. You can also do it yourself in global.asax.cs.